# how to replace latest character after a specific sign using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is `hello-word-the-code-123` and I want to change it to `hello-word-the-code-x` (replace 123 with x, using regex)

I tried `hello-word-the-code-123.replace(/\-\d$/, '-' + i)` but it give me `hello-word-the-code-123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only matching a single digit after the last `-`, but your input has 3 digits. Use `\d+` to match any number of digits.

```js
let i = 'x';
console.log('hello-word-the-code-123'.replace(/-\d+$/, '-' + i));
```

There's no need to escape `-`. It has no special meaning unless it's inside `[]`.